# kill a process after some time

Tags: c, time, posix, cpu

i've found this piece of code and tested it.

```
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t start_time;
  time_t current_time;
  int TIMEOUT=5;
  start_time = time(NULL);
  current_time = time(NULL);

  while (current_time < start_time + TIMEOUT)
  {
  //do everything here
  current_time = time(NULL);
  }

}
```

It works like a charm, but it takes completely one cpu off.
Is there a way to don't waste so much cpu?
Thanks

Edit, I can't use sleep, i must do other thing during waiting

Comment: Use the `sleep()` function.

Comment: Or the `alarm()` function if you want to do other things while the timer runs.

Comment: alarm will use 100% of cpu, however?

Comment: No it won't. It sets a timer, and sends a signal when the timer goes off. Meanwhile, your program just does whatever you have in "do everything here".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a timer.  There are several APIs to do this.

Just using `alarm` is the simpliest.

There is `setitimer/getitimer`.

There is the `timer_create/timer_destroy/timer_settime` family.

Each has their own strengths offset by their own complexities.